# K8s - add kubeadm to existing cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, orchestration, kubelet, kubespray

I have the cluster created many time ago without kubeadm (maybe it was kubespray, but the configuration for that also lost).
Is any way exists to add nodes to that cluster or attach kubeadm to current configuration or extend without erasing by kubespray?

Answer (score -2):

If Kubeadm was used to generate the original cluster then you can log into the Master and run `kubeadm token generate`. This will generate an API Token for you. With this API token your worker nodes will be able to preform an authenticated CSR against your Master to perform a joining request. You can follow [this guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-join/) from there to add a new node with the command `kubeadm join`.